# If I have deleted a keyboard shortcut in VS Code, is there any way to get it back?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, shortcut, vscode-keybinding

In the scene to edit my shortcut key to run the cell for notebook i need to change the keyboard shortcut where i change and in order to undo things i clicked remove keybindings instead of reset keybindings and i am not able to find the initial shortcut in the list none of mine how to get it back.?

also i want to ask how to export these keyboard shortcuts when in case of damage to the keybindings in the future show it will acts as backup

i did not tried any thing i search for google but not find anything